# Meaning of ご帰還あそばれなされた

Tags: meaning, verbs, conjugations, passive-voice, causation

Full sentence:
「俺様がご帰還あそばれなされたぞ！」
I think this sentence means something alike to: "I have returned!"

My main problem with this sentence is the usage of あそばれなされた.
From my understanding, this is the verb 遊ぶ, and looks like it's conjugated to it's causative-passive form on the past tense?
This conjugation looks really weird, I have checked Jisho and I'm not sure which conjugation it seems to be, but regardless of this I'm not sure what the verb 遊ぶ could be doing in this sentence together with 帰還.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4018/9831

Comment: Oh it's closed? I think ご帰還あそばれなされる is not correct. I think it should be ご帰還あそばされる or ご帰還あそばす.

Comment: As chocolate said, this あそばされなされた is a strange combination of two honorific expressions, and you must not use it in serious settings. But this one is perhaps an intentional wordplay (he calls himself 俺様 and is using honorific expressions to himself). Maybe this is something like "Behold the great return of me!"